# Como faço animação css?

Tags: html, css, aplicação-web, transição

estava navegando pela net e encontrei um site com uma animação bem legal mas não consegui descobrir o nome nem como faz. Admito, sou iniciante com linguagens web e gostaria de saber se alguem sabe dizer como faço tal animação. Segue o link do site: http://www.zero3design.com/portfolio-item/comunicacao-digital/

É a transição que acontece ao passar o mouse em cima da foto, ela surge acompanhando a trajetória do mouse.

Desde já agradeço pela atenção de todos.

Answer (score 1):

Esse tipo de animação pode ser feito de duas formas, CSS ou JavaScript.
Eu prefiro utilizar CSS sempre que possível, dependendo de onde for utilizar.

Seguem alguns links de como fazer com CSS:

- [Animação ao passar mouse - Hover](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/)
- [Criar animações em CSS3](http://tableless.com.br/animation-css3-criar-animacoes-css3-nunca-foi-tao-facil/)
- [Transições e animações em CSS](http://tableless.com.br/transition-e-animation/)

Answer (score 0):

Bom, isso foi feito com javascript, pode até abrir o inspecionar elemento e ir la no console.

Você teria que sair verificando se ele fez mouseover, e mouseout por esquerda por cima por direita ou por baixo.